# wp_insert_post multi upload Images

Tags: php, image, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to upload multiple images with wp_insert_post but only the last image of multiple uploads insert there other images uploaded but didn't attach there...

Here is code

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="agp_gallery[]" id="agp_image_files" style="width:90%; margin-left:5px;" multiple>
</form>
```

Here is function multiupload

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['agp_gallery'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
       if ($files['name'][$key]) {
          $file = array(
            'name' => $files['name'][$key],
            'type' => $files['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error' => $files['error'][$key],
            'size' => $files['size'][$key]
          );
     
          $_FILES = array("agp_gallery" => $file);
     
          foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        
              agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id, $result['caption']);
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Here is main function

```
function agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id, $caption){
    
  if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
 
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
 
  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
 
  update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attachment_id);

  $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attachment_id,
    'post_excerpt' => $caption
  );
  
  wp_update_post($attachment_data);

  return $attachment_id;

}
```

I get this above code from here:-

http://madebyraygun.com/blog/2012/upload-and-attach-multiple-images-from-the-wordpress-front-end/

and all code here:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id){
    
  if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
    
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
 
  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
  update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attachment_id));

  return $attachment_id;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

every time agp_process_wooimage is running it replaces the meta data of a certain post id:

post id = 33 meta data of '_product_image_gallery' only the last file is in there as the files before have been replaced.

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: in best case give the meta data "_product_image_gallery" a numbering or save an array instead of one value.

$array = get_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery');
$array = array_push($array, $attachment_id);
update_post_meta($post_id, $array);

Comment: function agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id, $setthumb='false'){
 
  if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
 
 
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
 
  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
 
 $array = get_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery'); 
 $array = array_push($array, $attachment_id); 

 
  if ($setthumb)  update_post_meta($post_id, $array);

  return $attachment_id;

}

Comment: i used above code but receive a error Missing argument 3 for update_post_meta(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\dwell\wp-content\plugins\advance-guest-post\lib\agp-functions.php on line 270 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\dwell\wp-includes\post.php on line 1817

Comment: awesome now its working just one issue it showing this error Warning: Missing argument 3 for update_post_meta(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\dwell\wp-content\plugins\advance-guest-post\lib\agp-functions.php on line 267 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\dwell\wp-includes\post.php on line 1817 on line 267 this code :- update_post_meta($post_id, $array);

Comment: missed one argument    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attachment_id);

Comment: I cant get this to work? only the last image is getting added to the product post